# Get Ask and Bid Option Prices from Fidelity's Website Using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I was able to get ask/bid option prices for a particular option from Fidelity Brokerage's web site using Google Sheets and importXML - but no longer.  I think the site changed.

The website to access Option prices is now:

https://researchtools.fidelity.com/ftgw/mloptions/goto/detailedQuote?symbols=-BTI220819P40&type=o-NavBar

where **-BTI220819P40** is the particular put option.

When I view the source page, I can see the bid and ask elements I'm interested in.
Here's a portion of the source page for the above link:

```
                                <div>
                                    <p class="bav-header">Bid</p>
                                    <p class="bav-value">
                                                41.86 X 5
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="bav-header ">Ask</p>
                                    <p class="bav-value">
                                                42.08 X 4
                                    </p>
                                </div>
```

When I attempt to obtain those values with importXML in Google Sheets I get "Error: Imported content is empty".

`=importXML("https://researchtools.fidelity.com/ftgw/mloptions/goto/detailedQuote?symbols=-BTI220715P40&type=o-NavBar", "//p[@class='bav-value']")`

Can anyone tell me how to get these bid and ask values?

Comment: I think you have to be registered to access that link ... so I wasn't able to try to help you

Comment: Yes, @Daniele I believe that's right - you have to log-in to Fidelity's web site on one of the tabs of your browser.